# Extend div all the way to bottom without scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i've got a problem where I can't seem to extend a div all the way to the bottom. I've looked here on stackoverflow and found some topics about it and tried it out but it doesn't work 100%, it always creates a scrollbar also.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for my project btw.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Divespotter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
      }
    </style>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                                   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="brand" href="#">DIVESPOTTER</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">ONTDEK</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">GALLERIJ</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">FORUM</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">BLOG</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="maincontent">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span6">
            <p class="title">Hét digitaal logboekje.</p>
            <p class="intro">Het logboek is een belangrijk onderdeel voor dé beste duikervaring. Divespotter helpt u deze ervaringen nooit meer zal vergeten.</p>

            <p class="register"><a href="#" >REGISTREER NU!</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="span6">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>
              <!-- Carousel items -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item">
                  <img src="img/afb1.jpg"/>
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    Eerste afbeelding
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img/afb2.jpg"/>
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    Tweede afbeelding
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img/afb3.jpg"/>
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    Derde afbeelding
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Carousel nav -->
              <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
              <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
            </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      </div>




    </div> 
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span4">
            <p>Log</p>
            <p>Leg al je duikervaringen vast zodat je er later terug van kan genieten precies of je erbij bent.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="span4">
            <p>Ontdek</p>
            <p>Ontdek nieuwe duiklocaties, leer van mededuikgenoten en bekijk foto’s van andere duikers over de hele wereld.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="span4">
            <p>Deel</p>
            <p>Deel al je duikervaringen en foto’s met je vrienden op Facebook, Twitter, ...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div></div>

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

within the style.css:

```
html, body { height: 100%;}
body
{

    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.navbar .brand {

    color: #232222;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 20%;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-inverse .brand {
    color: #232323;
}

 .navbar-inverse .nav > li > a{

    color: #232323;
    font-size: 15px;

}

.navbar-inverse .nav .active > a, .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a:focus {

    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}



.maincontent {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #6eb3d2;
    .container {
        padding-top: 2%;
    }
}

.title {
    padding-top: 5%;
    color: #313131; /* text color + color overlay */
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-size: 41px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.intro {
    width: 70%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    color: #232222; /* text color + color overlay */
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;

}

.footer {


    background-color: #232323;
     height: 100%;
   width:100%;
   p {
    color: #fff;
   }
}

.register {
    margin-top: 6%;
    a {
        padding: 10px;
        color: #f6f6f6; // text color + color overlay
        font-family: "Montserrat";
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 242px;
        height: 61px;
        background-color: #1f7f5b; /* layer fill content + color overlay */
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #232323;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I want the .footer vertically expanded
Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MckJB/

Comment: Please turn this into a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) and specify what you want to stick to the bottom. Thanks!

Comment: As Andrew said, can you tell us which parent tag you want to vertically expand?

Comment: Edited my question with Jsfiddle and the parent tag is footer

Comment: I'm abit confused with your question, are you trying to put the footer at the bottom without the scrollbar? Here's an example I build before http://artstartgrant.com.au/WhatsOn. Let me know if you don't understand, i can do a quick mockup for you, if this what you after

Comment: If you look at http://www.planjetweets.be you can see the grey area at the bottom. I have it set on 100% height but that creates a scrollbar. I just want that scrollbar gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What browser support do you need?

If you’re ok with

- Safari
- Chrome
- Firefox
- Opera 12.1+
- IE10+

you can use Flexbox to do this trivially. The only issue is it is a bit verbose as there are three syntax out in the wild.

First remove any margin and set `html` and `body` to be 100% height and width (Firefox needs the width set to fix a bug where the elements don't expand correctly):

```
html, body { 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; /* needed to fix Firefox bug */
    margin: 0; 
}
```

Next set the body to use flexbox rather than the regular box model. Safari, older Chrome, and Firefox use an old syntax. IE10 uses an in-between syntax, and Opera and modern Chrome use the new syntax (latter with prefix):

```
body {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

Next we need to make the elements to be stacked vertically rather than horizontally. Again, with various syntax. Add these to your `body` selector:

```
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
```

Now everything will be laid out vertically but all the elements will have their default with. We want the header and the footer to not stretch so they can stay as they are. However ,we want the main contents to stretch to fill the available space, so we need to say the element is flexible. In the demo I used an article element, so I did the following:

```
article {
    background-color: #6EB3D2;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

The value 1 means take up one unit worth of space. As no other item is flexible, this is all of the space. IF all three elements used 1, the available space would be sub-divided equally and added to the default size of the elements.

The final result should look something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Kf9TL/ (or http://jsfiddle.net/Kf9TL/show as a full page preview).

Is this what you want?

Comment: I still get the scrollbar with your solution. I put it online so you know what it is like: http://www.planjetweets.be

Comment: you haven't reset the padding on the body element. It adds 60px of top padding. That is part of the reason. The other is you're setting the footer to be 100% high. That is always going to create scrollbars.

Comment: I've deleted the padding on bottom element and the 100% height and it worked! Thanks